# Using creatine powder for fat loss

Tags: creatine

I know that using creatine powder puts water into your muscles and this makes your muscles look bigger as when I use to take it I looked more pumped.

I know that if your have more muscle then you burn more fat. Does this mean that if you take creatine along with exercise that you will burn fat much quicker than not taking creatine ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Not in the way you're thinking. The reason more muscle burns fat faster than less muscle is because there are physically more muscle cells that require nutrients to function. Creatine just holds water in the muscle which makes them look bigger. There isn't actually more muscle. Your TDEE remains consistent.

Creatine can help keep performance up. This in turn will help use more energy which helps in fat loss. That's all creatine will do for fat loss.

Comment: Correct. Creatine is a work enabler, i.e. it lets you work hard for a little longer, which in turn leads to increased muscle gains.

Comment: Okay I understand now thank you